# Masking Input in EditText in Android

Tags: android, masking

How to use inputfilter for CNIC i.e #####-#######-# ? Please help me.. I am new to Android and I dont know how to use it?

How to mask input? I went through various sites but couldn't find solution. I am so confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using [Masked EditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText) ? This is what you want ... :)

If you want a numeric keyboard instead of alphabetical, then comment the following lineof code:

```
this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

in the file `MaskedEditText.java`. Now setting `android:inputType = "numeric"` will work.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want but I can't find maskedEditText control in Eclipse IDE :(

Comment: Ok. I got it. let me check :)

Comment: you have to create that control manually as the framework doesn't have it by default. Follow the example given in the link above and you can do it ... :)

Comment: I added the jar file, I used   xmlns:mask="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.hospitalmanagement"> at the top of the root element but when I use control I get an error .. Please help

Comment: @awesum I have your exact same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Anyone interested, I ended up copying MaskedEditText's classes to my proyect and using xmlns:mask="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" on the root node.

Comment: how to set inputType to numeric, as it always show alphabetical keyboard?

Comment: @AliImran: I'll help you, but can you please upvote the answer first ? Thanks ... :)

Comment: @AliImran: have you tried using `android:inputType = "numeric"` ? It should work ... :)

Comment: @AliImran: actually it should work ... Also try `android:numeric = "decimal"`

Comment: @Y.S. I found a a bug in library code, So just commented this line " this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);" in this file "MaskedEditText"

Comment: This library worked for me only by setting the mask programmatically and not in xml: `editText.setMask("###-#######");`. Also, in android studio, if it nags you about the `xmlns` then this is probably the right line to add: `xmlns:mask="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`.

Answer (score 1):

) You can also try [the fork](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask) of Masked EditText. It's derived but with works with Gradle, has some bugfixes, an example project, and a little bit another behavior :-)

The behavior is also changed:

1. You can set the flag and the hint will be always visible.
2. Your pattern is invisible initially and grows automatically as soon, as you type. For instance, in the beginning, it is: "+7(", then you type '999' and it shows you "+7(999)" with another brace. In the original library, AFAIK it works like: "+7(   )  -  -  ", then you type '999' and it transforms into "+7(999)  -  -  " and so on.

Comment: please make this library compatible with v23 or lower versions.